# Не отображает ActionBar на телефоне

Tags: java, android-studio

Не показывает меню  в приложении. Читал, что может помочь смена DarkActionBar на NoActionBar - не помогло. Вот код MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_shuffle:
            musicSrv.setShuffle();
            break;
        case R.id.action_end:
            stopService(playIntent);
            musicSrv=null;
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.resonance1.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
        android:icon="@drawable/rand"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Shuffle"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_end"
        android:icon="@drawable/end"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="End" />
</menu>
```

Main Activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3EDED"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/song_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Вот это не добавляется на главную activity]
[image: Activity main - где должнa показываться ActionBar]

Comment: я правильно понимаю, это на ActionBar добавляет справа кнопку(троеточие) с выпадающем меню?

Comment: не совсем так, я внес изменения в свой вопрос. Первый скрин как раз то что должно добавляться на главную активити (я немного не понял, как подписывать изображения)

Comment: Применяемая к этой активити тема в манифесте содержит action bar?

Comment: нет, а как это реализовать?